# Extract part of sql query (numbers) using regex

Tags: regex

I need to extract part of sql query (saved in file) - numbers in section `IN`. But sql query also has other numbers (but not in section `IN`) What pattern should i use?
Pattern `'(\d+)'` extract more numbers that i need (from other part of sql query).

```
" IN ('7',
'9',
'11',
'13',
'14',
'24')"
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor? `(?:\G(?!^)',\s*'|\bIN\s*\(')\K\d+` might do the job, see https://regex101.com/r/4muX0O/1

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
(?:\G(?!^)',\s*'|\bIN\s*\(')\K\d+
(?<=\bIN\s*\([^()]*)\d+
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/4muX0O/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/4muX0O/2).

**Regex #1** (compliant with Boost, PCRE, Onigmo regex libraries):

- `(?:\G(?!^)',\s*'|\bIN\s*\(')` - end of the previous match and then `'`, `,`, zero or more whitespace and then a `'`, or a whole word `IN` followed with `('` substring
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the currently matched text
- `\d+` - one or more digits

**Regex #2** (compliant with JavaScript ECMAScript 2018+, .NET, PyPi regex):

- `(?<=\bIN\s*\([^()]*)` - a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `\bIN` - whole word `IN`
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\d+` - one or more digits.